# android get usb_interface_descriptor, usb_endpoint_descriptor

Tags: android, linux, usb, libusb

In the method [usb_device_new()](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/system/core/libusbhost/usbhost.c#353) they are reading the [usb_device_descriptor](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/usb/ch9.h#L217) with this function call:

`read(fd, device->desc, sizeof(device->desc));`

First of all how does that even work, to read from the file descriptor after you have opened the device. How do you know that the usb_device_descriptor is what will be read? I find that somewhat confusing.

And the second question that I have is how can I read the [usb_interface_descriptor](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/usb/ch9.h#L308) and the [usb_endpoint_descriptor](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/usb/ch9.h#L326) from the usb_device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found how they manage to retrive the interface and endpoints details:

```
while ((desc = usb_descriptor_iter_next(&iter)) != NULL) 
    {
        if (desc->bDescriptorType == USB_DT_INTERFACE) 
        {
            struct usb_interface_descriptor *interface = (struct usb_interface_descriptor *) desc;

            interfaceValues.add(interface->bInterfaceNumber);
            interfaceValues.add(interface->bInterfaceClass);
            interfaceValues.add(interface->bInterfaceSubClass);
            interfaceValues.add(interface->bInterfaceProtocol);
            interfaceValues.add(interface->bNumEndpoints);
        } 
        else if (desc->bDescriptorType == USB_DT_ENDPOINT) 
        {
            struct usb_endpoint_descriptor *endpoint = (struct usb_endpoint_descriptor *) desc;

            endpointValues.add(endpoint->bEndpointAddress);
            endpointValues.add(endpoint->bmAttributes);
            endpointValues.add(__le16_to_cpu(endpoint->wMaxPacketSize));
            endpointValues.add(endpoint->bInterval);
        }
    }
```

I just had to dig a little bit deeper in the framework, in [this](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/jni/com_android_server_UsbHostManager.cpp) file.